# Porting app from Kafka 0.8.2.1 to Kafka 0.9.0. Reading offsets issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we are experiencing a problem related to the migration of the code of our application from version 0.8.2.1 to 0.9.0.0 of Apache Kafka.

We are referring, in this case, to the version of Kafka released by Cloudera:

kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0-kafka-1.3.2

kafka_2.11-0.9.0-kafka-2.0.2

We detected the problem when reading and writing the offsets on the __consumer_offsets metadata topic.
In particular, we use a BlockingChannel to connect to the Kafka Broker and, at the time of the receive() method call we get a EOFException.

In particular:

```
java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel (NetworkReceive.java:83)
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely (BlockingChannel.scala: 129)
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive (BlockingChannel.scala: 120)
```

One possible cause could be the differences between the two versions of Kafka API.

**Kafka 0.8.2**

in our app, we call

```
ConsumerMetadataResponse.readFrom(channel.receive().buffer())
```

the receive method is as follows

```
def receive(): Receive = {
    if(!connected)
      throw new ClosedChannelException()

    val response = new BoundedByteBufferReceive()
    response.readCompletely(readChannel)

    response
}
```

as we can see it returns a kafka.network.Receive, which is a trait that extends the trait kafka.network.Transmission.
In this Receive, the buffer method exists and is overridden in kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive

```
def buffer: ByteBuffer = {
    expectComplete()
    contentBuffer
  }
```

**Kafka 0.9.0**

We changed the previous line to

```
GroupCoordinatorResponse.readFrom(channel.receive().payload())
```

the receive method in this version of the API is as follows

```
 def receive(): NetworkReceive = {
    if(!connected)
      throw new ClosedChannelException()

    val response = readCompletely(readChannel)
    response.payload().rewind()

    response
  }

  private def readCompletely(channel: ReadableByteChannel): NetworkReceive =     {
    val response = new NetworkReceive
    while (!response.complete())
      response.readFromReadableChannel(channel)
    response
  }
```

As we can see, this returns instead a kafka.network.NetworkReceive, which is a class that implements the interface kafka.network.Receive, now written in java and completely different from the previous one.
Here there is no buffer method, but only a payload method that returns the contents of

```
    private ByteBuffer buffer;
```

How could we solve?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka 0.9 maintains the old Kafka consumer in order to achieve backward-compatibility with Kafka 0.8.2 brokers.
You are using the old consumer which is still present in Kafka 0.9 to read messages from Kafka 0.9.
You should start to use new consumer API of Kafka 0.9 to read data from Kafka 0.9 brokers.

Hope this helps.